# Retrieve 1 million rows of user record in postgress

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am preping for a Notification service in which a single notification can be broadcasted to 1 million users at once. What are the available options to store the users record so that i can retrieve it faster in under < 1-2 secs. Is postgress the right tool for this ? Postgres can handle huge data, but will it help for my use case. In any case, can we do better job than

1. `Select * from users LIMIT 2000 OFFSET 0` ( in batches ) -> This also takes linear time (*, here is just a ref, not going to use it)
2. Concurrent connections to pull data. (But have a issue finding the right offset when querying)
3. Partitioning the table into chunks (But, seems still I need retreive 1 million records under < 1- 2secs)
4. Do i need to think to put the data in a different way or different tool.

Could be a basic question. But clearly not finding enough solutions. Any one has idea, worked on a environment who has data like this ?

Comment: It sounds like pub/sub to me. Publish a notification using NATS or similar. Let the user subscribe and get the notification?

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you are trying to do. What is being broadcast? To database users or other users? Are you talking about activity within the database or not?

Comment: Consider this example, broadcasting to a topic. A topic can contain many users associated to it. Once a notification to the topic is triggered, we need to find all the users on that topic and their prefs and make some business logics on top of it and then send it to queues for end user triggering. Here, I was try to know if a topic contains 1million users how to get them to do business logics i mentioned previously. Under  < 1-2 secs. All topic and users relationships are maintained in separate tables. Hope this example clarifies. Activity inside Database  @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: @TheKeeper It would help if you provided data examples and your table structure in your Post. Do you have a table currently that stores the relation of `topics` to `users`?

Comment: As others have said, this needs clarifying. But fetching 1 million rows in less than 2 seconds is definitely possible, provided you have: (1) the right hardware for the database (2) the right network connectivity to the database. The general "secret sauce" to processing a lot of data in as short an elapsed time as possible is parallelism: run multiple connections to the database, each fetching, say 250K rows. With a single thread, I can fetch 1M rows out of my database (not PostgreSQL) in 3.5 seconds. The database runs in a Linux VM on my laptop.

Comment: Doing the same fetch on a database on a properly sized server completes in sub second times.

Answer (score 1):

Test data for a subscription table:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE subs( user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, topic_id INTEGER NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO subs SELECT n,n%1000 FROM generate_series(1,10000000) n;
INSERT INTO subs SELECT n,1000 FROM generate_series(1,1000000) n;
ALTER TABLE subs ADD PRIMARY KEY (topic_id, user_id);
VACUUM ANALYZE subs;
```

Topic 1000 has 1M subscribers. The index on (topic_id,user_id) is essential as it allows index_only scan when searching for users subscribed to a topic. All queries run on the same machine as postgres.

In order to parallelize fetching users subscribed to a topic, we have to cut the list of subscribers into chunks and send these chunks to parallel processes or threads. But in order to cut this list into equal sized chunks, we have to fetch it first, which is the thing we want to parallelize in the first place... so we can't.

Obviously, using LIMIT and OFFSET is not possible, because the server would still have to read all the rows skipped by OFFSET, in each parallel process. So the result could only be at best twice as fast, no matter what the number of parallel processes is, with a lot of wasted CPU cycles.

```
import time,psycopg2
from multiprocessing import Pool

def bench( f, *args, **kwargs ):
    t = time.time()
    try:
        return f( *args, **kwargs )
    finally:
        dt = time.time()-t
        print("%s: %.03f s" % (f.__name__, dt))

def single_threaded_fetch( topic_id ):
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT user_id FROM subs WHERE topic_id = %s", (topic_id,))
    return c.fetchall()

def single_threaded_nofetch( topic_id ):
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT user_id FROM subs WHERE topic_id = %s", (topic_id,))

def multi_threaded_fetch_chunk( chunk ):
    topic_id, min_user_id, max_user_id = chunk
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test")
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT user_id FROM subs WHERE topic_id = %s AND user_id BETWEEN %s AND %s", (topic_id,min_user_id,max_user_id))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    print(chunk, len(rows))


def multi_threaded_fetch( topic_id, nthreads=5, chunk_size=100000 ):
    c = db.cursor()
    # get min and max user_ids
    c.execute( "SELECT min(user_id), max(user_id) FROM subs WHERE topic_id = %s", (topic_id,))
    min_id, max_id = c.fetchone()
    
    # cut it in chunks and hope they will be of equal size
    chunks = [(topic_id, n,n+chunk_size-1) for n in range( min_id, max_id+1, chunk_size )]
    chunks[-1] = (topic_id, chunks[-1][1], max_id )

    # perform parallel queries
    with Pool( nthreads ) as p:
        p.map( multi_threaded_fetch_chunk, chunks )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test")
    # r = bench( single_threaded_fetch, 1000 )
    # r = bench( single_threaded_nofetch, 1000 )
    r = bench( multi_threaded_fetch, 1000 )
```

This fetches the minimum and maximum user_ids of the subscribers to the topic, then cuts the list into chunks and fetches them in parallel.

```
single_threaded_fetch: 0.231 s
single_threaded_nofetch: 0.138 s
multi_threaded_fetch: 0.078 s
```

Speedup from parallel fetch is not spectacular. The "single_threaded_nofetch" case, which does the query but does not convert the returned rows to python objects, only takes 138ms.

In this test case, the parallel case has an advantage: user_ids subscribing to the topic are contiguous. This would not be the case in a real implementation: each chunk would contain a random number of rows, possibly none. This means the parallel results are over-optimistic.

I'm not fetching rows from users table in this example, because once you have the id's, this is trivial to parallelize. The problem is getting the list of user_ids.

So, if the problem is fetching rows from users table it would be simpler to:

- Fetch the full list of user_ids subscribing to the topic from the subs table (index only scan)
- Cut it in chunks, and parallelize fetching from users table.

This presents the problem that each chunk consisting of a list of user_id's will result in something like:

```
WHERE user_id IN (huge list with a gorillion values)
```

...which is probably be going to be just as slow to generate and parse than what the parallel processing saves. In fact, the solution above begins to look better: we have a subs table with a multicolumn index, all we need are chunk boundaries. Then:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users JOIN subs USING (user_id) WHERE subs.topic_id=...
AND user_id BETWEEN min_user_id AND max_user_id
```

Since the problem is to calculate boundaries for equal size chunks of user_ids, the solution is to precalculate and cache them. Say we decide to cut a topic into 4 equal sized chunks, with boundaries user_id_1,user_id_2,user_id_3, we can then cache these values and make parallel queries like the previous SELECT, with the condition on user_id being:

```
Process 1: user_id < user_id_1
Process 2: user_id BETWEEN user_id_1 AND user_id_2-1
Process 3: user_id BETWEEN user_id_2 AND user_id_3-1
Process 4: user_id >= user_id_3
```

This will return correct results even if boundaries are out of date.

This could be cached in the topics table, in the form of an array of user_id's which represent chunk boundaries. Setting it to NULL could mean that it's a topic with few subs, thus no need to parallelize.

However, if you're doing pub/sub, why are you not using MQTT?